# MacBook not sleeping when I close the lid

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake

My MacBook has never slept when I close the lid. I´ve tried all the remedies listed here in the forum from resets to experimenting with pmset settings.

Should my MacBook sleep as soon as I close the lid just like pressing alt+cmd+eject or does it sleep according to the power settings? I.e. after 10 minutes if so set?

Here is the output of `pmset -g`

```
Active Profiles:
Battery Power       -1*
AC Power        -1
Currently in use:
 standbydelay         4200
 standby              0
 halfdim              1
 sms                  1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 disksleep            10
 sleep                10
 hibernatemode        3
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         1
 acwake               0
 lidwake              1
```

Using `syslog | grep -i "wake reason"` gives no results?

I have reviewed my sharing settings and deactivated everything, checked that there is no print queue and bluetooth is off.

Can anyone help me get my MacBook to sleep when I close the lid?

Comment: what is this "sudo pmset -a displaysleep 1syslog | grep -i "wake reason"

Comment: it should have been "syslog | grep -i "wake reason" "...the two line got put into one

Answer (score 2):

First thing - if "Internet sharing" is on and you are connected to power your Macbook won't sleep, though it does turn the display off.

To start can we make sure that the computer will actually sleep.

Select "Sleep" in the Apple menu. Now wake the computer. Note the time. Do the same thing again ten minutes later but this time sleep the computer, close the lid, wait a couple of minutes then open it. Note the time again. Does this wake the computer?

I like to open Console rather than use the syslog so run Console and select "All Messages" under "System Log Queries". Now we can search in the log easily for both "wake" and "sleep".

When looking at the results for "wake" you should see some kernel messages that tell you either it waked due to a lid open "EC.LidOpen" or you touched the keyboard which will log a kernel message "The USB device Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad (Port 2 of Hub at 0xfa100000) may have caused a wake by issuing a remote wakeup (3)"

When looking for "sleep" the most interesting lines are those that log the AirPort power change as they mark actual system sleeps. If you have "Power Nap" turned on the  you will also see kernel messages logged by RTC for "Maintenance" and "SleepService" which tells you that at time the computer was asleep but partially woke up for RTC to do it's thing.

For sleep though the best to look for is a message from WindowServer "handle_will_sleep_auth_and_shield_windows: Deferring" which it logs at sleep time.

What does 'pmset -g assertions' give you? Are there any lines set to '1'?

Given all that what do you learn about how your computer is sleeping and waking?

If it doesn't wake on a lid open perhaps you have a hardware problem?

Comment: Jan 25 12:49:26 Roberts-MacBook-Pro kernel[0] : sleep Jan 25 12:49:26 Roberts-MacBook-Pro kernel[0] : Wake reason: EHC2 Jan 25 13:01:55 Roberts-MacBook-Pro kernel[0] : AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerChange: System Wake - Full Wake/ Dark Wake / Maintenance wake

Comment: and later.....Jan 25 13:03:04 Roberts-MacBook-Pro kernel[0] : sleep Jan 25 13:03:04 Roberts-MacBook-Pro kernel[0] : Wake reason: EHC2 Jan 25 22:11:20 Roberts-MacBook-Pro kernel[0] : AirPort_Brcm43xx::powerChange: System Wake - Full Wake/ Dark Wake / Maintenance wake

Comment: Did it wake on a lid open? Does it sleep at some point?

Comment: NO it doesn´t wake on lid-up and it sleeps after 10 minutes as set in the energie options...but not immediately after lid-down

Answer (score 2):

Do you have anything connected to the MiniDisplay port? My MacBook won't sleep on closing the lid if I've got an AV adapter connected.

Comment: No nothing connected.

Comment: I can see a reason to prevent it from sleeping if you have it hooked up to an external monitor but there should be an option in Preferences if there's not.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of testing on the mother board i found that if you have a faulty battery indicator, or if the battery indicator plug on the mother board is not connected or has come undone, your apple and screen will not go to sleep when closed. this is the plug next to the battery connector on the mother board.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is specific to Macbook Air.  Mine is a 13" mid2012, but this should apply to most models of the Air, and may apply to MBP from similar timeframe as well.

Once you have tried these software and OS fixes, if nothing works, you may have a fault in your I/O board.  This is the board that connects the power, iSight camera, microphone, headphones, and one USB port to the logic board.

It also holds the sensor that can tell when your laptop closes.

Take a small refrigerator magnet and run it along the side of your keyboard near the port for the magsafe charger.  You are trying to find the lid sensor.  When you see the screen go dark, you've found the sensor.  Leave the magnet right over that spot.  If your I/O board is in good shape, the display will stay dark.  If your screen flickers on and off, your I/O is faulty and should be replaced.

It's a $50-80 board, and with a pentalobe 5 and small hex star driver, replacing the board is fairly easy.  There is a good how-to at ifixit.com

After weeks of trying to track down a software issue, I did this replacement myself and it solved the problem right away and for good.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I got my MacBook to sleep again when I disabled automatic backups with Time Machine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the answer was **battery indicator module**. In fact I didn't have that module at all so after buying one and placing it in the right place (under the battery on the side where battery indicator button is placed of course) the issue was solved and sleep mode worked in a normal way by closing the lid. So try replacing the module, it's not expensive. Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Could you send me a link or picture of the part you bought? Do you mean this part? (https://www.ebay.de/i/303138266308)

Comment: That's exactly the part. your's seems to be expensive. I bought it for about 10$. Make sure to get three screws with it cause those are small screws hard to find replacement I guess.